# Extract time (HMS) from lubridate date time object?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have the following datetime:

> t <- "2018-05-01 23:02:50 UTC"

I want to split it to time and date.

When I apply date(t) I get the date part.
But when I use lubridate's `hms`, `parse_date_time` and other functions to do this in `"HMS"` order I get `NA`.

I have checked other answers here on SOF but for some reason it gives me `NA`.

Please advise how to extract it.

I want to understand why:

```
strftime(t, format="%H:%M:%S")
```

will do the job but what I am missing in `lubridate::hms` or `parse_date_time`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My solution is to install `library(anytime)`:

```
date <- anytime::anydate(t)
time <- strftime(t, format="%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 18):

Is this what you were looking for? It can now be done more simply with hms::as_hms.

```
> library(lubridate)
> library(hms)
> as_hms(ymd_hms("2018-05-01 23:02:50 UTC"))
23:02:50

> t <- "2018-05-01 23:02:50 UTC"
> as_hms(ymd_hms(t))
23:02:50
```

Answer (score 6):

What you are missing in `lubridate`'s `hms()` is that it expects "a character vector of hour minute second triples" as an argument. There's no provision for handling a string which also contains date info. Hence, the output of `Sys.Date()` or `lubridate::now()` doesn't work as input to `lubridate::hms()`.

In case you want a `tidyverse` solution, here's one:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

now()
#> [1] "2018-08-13 16:41:31 BST"

get_time <- function(time = now()) {
  time %>%
    str_split(" ") %>%
    map_chr(2) %>%
    hms()
}

get_time()
#> [1] "16H 41M 31S"

get_time("2018-05-01 23:02:50 UTC")
#> [1] "23H 2M 50S"
```

Created on 2018-08-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
  library(hms)
    t <- "2018-05-01 23:02:50 UTC"
    unlist(strsplit(t," "))[2]%>%hms::parse_hms()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without including just another package (`hms` on top of `lubridate`):

```
t <- "2018-05-01 23:02:50 UTC"

sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour(t), minute(t), second(t))

"23:02:50"
```

Answer (score 0):

The fucntion in Lubridate package exists, it is called "hour()", here the official guide:
https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/hour

```
t <- "2018-05-01 23:02:50 UTC"

lubridate::hour(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting a solution that I have used to extract either ymd or the hms independently after a `lubridate` conversion. I noticed OP mentioned wanting to separate both time and date so for future SO users who may find themselves here I included the regex's used for both below. assuming df contains a column called `date` where time is formated ymd_hms like so `"2018-05-01 23:02:50 UTC"`:

```
library(stringr)
df <- df %>%
   mutate(
    time = str_extract(date, "[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}") #to extract hms time
    day = str_extract(date, "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}") #to extract ymd time
)
```